# Struts2 file copying to different folder after file upload?

Tags: java, struts2

I am uploading users profile picture via struts2 file upload interceptor. After uploading the picture I want to save it inside my webapp under webapp/upload/images folder. I used following code to do this.

```
public String uploadPhoto() {
    try {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getContextPath() + "/uploads/images";
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

But I am getting following error

```
Server path:/picvik/uploads/images
java.io.IOException: Destination '/picvik/uploads/images/one.jpg' directory cannot be created
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:777)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:731)
    at com.picvik.action.ChangePhotoAction.uploadPhoto(ChangePhotoAction.java:28)
```

Please correct what I am doing wrong. And how to achieve this. I basically want to save all users profile picture inside my webapp under:  webapp/uploads/images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple, you CANNOT create a file using a relative path, you should use its real path:

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getContextPath().getRealPath("/uploads/images");
```

It should be OK then.

Comment: With the caveat that you almost certainly shouldn't save images to a directory within the web app, for a variety of reasons.